# Entity Framework Access collection of collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I'm trying to access a collection of a collection of my main model in my Details action of my controller.  But I keep getting the following error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property expression 'e => {from Color color in [e].Colors select [color].Images}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.'

this pops up on the line:

```
var model = _context.Towers
    .Include(e => e.Colors.Select(color => color.Images))
    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);
```

Here's some of the other code:

**Tower.cs**

```
public class Tower 
{
    [Key]
    public Nullable<int> ID { get; set; }
    public List<Color> Colors { get; set; } = new List<Color>();
}
```

**Color.cs**

```
public class Color 
{
    [Key]
    public Nullable<int> ID { get; set; }
    public string ColorHash { get; set; }
    public List<Image> Images { get; set; } = new List<Image>();
}
```

**Image.cs**

```
public class Image
{
    [Key]
    public Nullable<int> ID { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

I need to be able to access the ***Images*** associated with each ***Color*** associated with the ***Tower*** I'm showing details for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be something like this:

```
var model = _context.Towers
    .Include(e => e.Colors)
        .ThenInclude(color => color.Images))
    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);
```

Comment: Yup. That was it. Thank you so much